# Resetting the root password for mysql 8 in ansible on centos stream 9

Tags: mysql, ansible

Hi I'm kind of lost here with the following issue.

All I'm trying to do is setup and install mysql 8 on centos stream 9. This should be fairly easy (I've done this before on earlier versions of both). But for some reason I cannot get the root password to reset in order to continue on to securing mysql.

I've tried the following

```
1) - name: Set new root pw with temp PASSWORD
 ansible.builtin.shell: mysql -u root -p --connect-expired-password -e "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '{{ centos_mysql_root_password }}';"
 
2) - name: Grab the temp root pw from /var/log/mysqld
  ansible.builtin.shell: >- grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | awk '{print $NF}' | tail -n 1
  register: mysql_root_temp_pw
  no_log: true

- name: Update root user password
  community.mysql.mysql_user:
    login_password: "{{ mysql_root_temp_pw.stdout }}"
    name: root
    password: "{{ centos_mysql_root_password }}"
    state: present

3) - name: Ensure root User Can Only Login from Localhost
  community.mysql.mysql_user:
    login_password: "{{ centos_mysql_root_password }}"
    check_implicit_admin: yes
    name: root
    host: "{{ item }}"
    password: "{{ centos_mysql_root_password }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
    - localhost
    - 127.0.0.1
    - ::1
  
- name: Add .my.cnf to Root Home Directory
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: my.cnf.j2
    dest: /root/.my.cnf
```

If I run the first command it hangs as it does not quote the ALTER USER command correctly (even if I turn it into a variable and use {{ var | quote }} )
Every other command I run I usually get an error about not being able to connect as root to localhost although I have no idea how thats possible since its a fresh install and I have not run mysql_secure_installation yet.

Comment: FWIW. See an [example](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-freebsd-mysql/blob/master/tasks/secret.yml) on how to manage the MySQL temporary password for root. See also how to [test](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-freebsd-mysql/blob/master/tasks/assert.yml) it. There are useful links and comments in the code. If this doesn't help you you might want to ask [community.mysql](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.mysql) how is it possible they don't provide a solution for this ?!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this closed, the issue was the following.

In the original question I was installing the following rpm to install mysql.

https://repo.mysql.com/mysql80-community-release-el9-1.noarch.rpm

Then installing mysql-community-server. While using that I kept seeing the above issue.

I deleted that version of mysql and removed the rpm, I then installed the default version of mysql that comes with centos-stream9, the packages I installed are below.

1. mysql.x86_64
2. mysql-common.x86_64
3. mysql-errmsg.x86_64
4. mysql-selinux.noarch
5. mysql-server.x86_64

With these installed the following ansible task works.

```
- name: Set mysql root password
      ansible.builtin.shell: mysql -NBe "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '{{ centos_mysql_root_password }}';"
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with the mysql-community-server version. But for now the solution at least for me is to install default mysql 8 packages on centos-stream9.

Answer (score 0):

[I've build this once](https://github.com/csuka/ansible_role_percona_xtradb_cluster/blob/main/tasks/root.yml) for CentOS 8, and I think the logic hasn't changed.

Only do this when installed mysql for the first time:

```yaml
    - name: root | stop mysql
      systemd:
        name: mysql
        state: stopped
   
    - name: root | place temporary cnf file
      template:
        src: temp_cnf.j2
        dest: /etc/my.cnf
        mode: 0644

    - name: root | start and enable mysql
      systemd:
        name: mysql
        state: started
        enabled: true

    - name: root | get temp root password
      shell: >-
        grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log |
        awk '{print $NF}' | tail -n 1
      register: temp_root_pw

    - name: root | set root password
      shell: >-
        mysqladmin -u root
        --password="{{ temp_root_pw.stdout }}"
        password "my_password_here"
```

Here are the contents of temp_cnf.j2:

```ini
[client]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
server-id=1
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Please take a good look at the file itself, as it does more than only configuring the root pw.